# Exporting images in a Mathematica array to a PDF s.t. each image is precisely $n \times m$ millimeter in dimension

Tags: export, image-processing, image, pdf-format

I have a number of images in a Mathematica array, and I'd like to export the images to a PDF s.t. each image is precisely scaled to be $n \times m$ millimeters in dimension.  The idea is that printing the PDF out on $8.5$ by $11$ inch ($215.9$ mm $\times$ $279.4$ mm) paper will give me images that can be measured with a ruler to be $n \times m$ millimeters.

If the dimensions of the images are not precisely $n \times m$ millimeters in dimension, is there a simple way to do this?  I can also easily just apply `ImageCrop` to each image in the array as a preprocessing step.

Comment: @YvesKlett In this question, I need to scaling technique to work for an array of images.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question and add sample code and images.

Comment: @YvesKlett I solved my problem with a little work using the link you provided.  Thank you.  I would delete this question, however I'm having trouble registering.  Could you or another administrator help me delete my post?

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate. You might also consider self-answering and making your Q useful for future visitors. If you want it deleted, you can flag the question and get mod attention (or someone else does that for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you make a large graphic object the size of a page, say `ImageSize->{700, 1000}`, with some details like a grid.  Then experiment with the Mathematica print options for margins until you have something that consistently prints at a size you want with the margins you want.  Then you can `Inset` all the graphics you need with a predictable result.  See here for an example of `Inset` for page layout: [2 column documents in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138184/879601)

E.g.

```
... 
page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {330, 400}], 
    Inset[column1, {75, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}], 
    Inset[column2, {255, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}], 
    Inset[clippedimage, {165, 90}, {Center, Center}, {330, 179}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 330}, {0, 400}}, ImageSize -> 330];

nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[page, "Print"]];
NotebookPrint[nb];
NotebookClose[nb];
```

`ExpressionCell[..., "Print"]` is necessary for printing at the same size as the output from `Print[page]` would print.

Print output can then be directed to [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com) or [pdfFactory](http://www.pdffactory.co.uk), etc.